# Returning data from .Net EXE to Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters, exe, output-redirect

I have a powershell script that calls an executable to do some data crunching and the script needs to retrieve the results from by the executable file. Wondering what options I have on plate for this inter process communication

- Can I have the executable file directly return a string array or an object (I don't think this is possible)?
- Volatile variable that the exe file sets and the powershell script reads from?
- Spawn a temporary .Net remoting server within the executable and have the powershell ping that server to get the results

Comment: Pipes are designed for interprocess communication, although I don't know if a powershell script can do this kind of communication

Comment: Also check out this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506404/capture-return-value-of-an-net-exe-in-an-bat-file

Comment: Plus this: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/sl-SI/Offtopic/thread/691128c5-72a5-48c1-971e-50c6bccd8165 Man, you didn't google for the solution for long, have you? Both results came up on the first google page under ".net exe result" :)

Comment: Why not just spit out the results via stdout in XML or CSV format and have PowerShell slurp it up with either a cast to [xml] or ConvertFrom-Csv.

Comment: Thanks Keith! XML looks like the clean and scalable approach.

Comment: Thanks Nienawiedzony for your inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just spit out the results from the EXE to stdout in XML or CSV format and have PowerShell slurp it up with either a cast to [xml] or ConvertFrom-Csv.

Answer (score 0):

That the executable is written in .NET makes no difference: it will be a separate process and therefore only the mechanisms for passing data from one process to another (without specific support in *both*) are available:

- The return value from the exe: an integer.
- Standard output from the exe: a string (usually divided into separate lines by splitting on newlines and thus treated as an array).

(Theoretically standard error could also be used, but that would be abusing it for no additional functionality.)

The standard output approach is easiest: in the exe use [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) (which is a shortcut to [`Console.Out.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out.aspx)) and then parse the strings in PowerShell:

```
MyExe | Foreach-Object {
  # Do something with $_ which will be a string
}
```

Obviously any data format that can be encoded into strings can be used. Also the calling script could accumulate the whole output into a single value and process it all at once.